# How to Set Linux server Wordpress Plugin , Themes download server ask FTP hostname , FTP Username , FTP password .?

Tags: wordpress

This is Yuvaraj, I'm starting to learn `Linux ( Ubuntu 12.04 LTS )`. I have to install `WordPress` with localhost in my machine successfully. But I couldn't add any Plugins because of it ask `FTP` user name and `FTP` Password. How can I give this User name and password?

Could any one fix this problem...

Comment: Do you have installed Xampp / Wamp?

Comment: I have  installed Lampp(Xampp) Server

Comment: please check here, it will solve your issue : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-install-asks-for-ftp-details